# Resgatar botão através do id

Tags: c#, winforms

Boa noite, 
Estou desenvolvendo um grafo, trabalho acadêmico..

.. A ideia é fazer um "labirinto", então eu gero o mesmo em tempo de execução, e guardo uma "referência" de cada botão numa lista, mas cheguei num ponto onde preciso mudar a cor de um botão e surgiu a seguinte dúvida: se eu sei exatamente qual é o id do botão, como faço para que um método "pegue" esse botão para que eu possa manipular o mesmo? Segue o método que instancia a minha lista:

```
 private List<ListaVertices> CriarBotoes()
        {
        Point localizacao = new Point(0, 0);
        List<ListaVertices> lista = new List<ListaVertices>();
        int IdBtn = 0;
        int DimensaoBtn = 35;

        for (int y = 0; y < TamanhoY; y++)
        {

            Button b = new Button
            {
                Width = DimensaoBtn,
                Height = DimensaoBtn,
                Name = IdBtn.ToString(),
                Location = localizacao,

            };
            b.Text = b.Name;
            this.Controls.Add(b);
            ListaVertices ElementoY = new ListaVertices { IdVertice = IdBtn }; // adiciona novo elemento na lista.
            lista.Add(ElementoY); // adiciona novo elemento na lista.
            IdBtn++;

            localizacao.X += DimensaoBtn;

            for (int x = 0; x < TamanhoX; x++)
            {

                Button btn = new Button
                {
                    Width = DimensaoBtn,
                    Height = DimensaoBtn,
                    Name = IdBtn.ToString(),
                    Location = localizacao,
                };
                localizacao.X += DimensaoBtn;
                btn.Text = btn.Name;
                this.Controls.Add(btn);
                ListaVertices ElementoX = new ListaVertices { IdVertice = IdBtn }; // adiciona novo elemento na lista.
                lista.Add(ElementoX); // adiciona novo elemento na lista.
                IdBtn++;

            }
            localizacao.Y += DimensaoBtn;
            localizacao.X = 0;
        }

        return lista;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente com um pouco de Linq:

```
this.Controls.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "idButton");
```

Colocando em um método estático, como pediu:

```
public static Button GetButton(Form f, string id)
{
   return f.Controls.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == id);
}
```

Comment: E se eu quisesse acessar através de uma classe que não seja a do Form, é possível?

Comment: aí teria que passar o form como parâmetro... e no lugar do this o objeto do form. Qualquer coisa coloca um exemplo de como seria pra ver melhor

Comment: this.Controls é o meu form? eu tenho uma classe static que estão com meus métodos, só por organização

Comment: no caso desse comando estar dentro do seu form, o `this` é o próprio form. em um método estático, o this não funciona. Mas, basta colocar o form como parâmetro

Comment: alterei a resposta